# SAS how to carry over or retain value from row to row for comparison based on condition

Tags: sas, retain

I have some data that looks like this:

```
ID   linker    dis_date    lag_disdate  days_supply disdiff  length
A    000 ddd   2/7/2014                   30           .     62
A    000 ddd   3/7/2014     2/7/2014      30           26    62 
A    000 ddd   4/16/2014    3/7/2014      30           38    62
A    000 ddd   5/19/2014    4/16/2014     30           31    62
A    000 ddd   7/17/2014    5/19/2014     30           57    62
A    000 ddd   9/11/2014    7/17/2014     30           54    62
```

The logic is that if the disdiff is less than length, the date1 would be the previous disdate or lag_disdate but date2 would be the current dis_date minus one.  However this is compared from each row to the next row.  So the ideal outcome would look like this:

```
ID  date1      date2       disdate
A                          2/7/2014                        
A   2/7/2014   3/6/2014    3/7/2014
A   2/7/2014   4/15/2014   4/16/2014
A   2/7/2014   5/18/2014   5/19/2014
A   2/7/2014   7/16/2014   7/17/2014
A   2/7/2014   9/10/2014   9/11/2014
```

I tried to use a DoW loop to achieve this:

```
data test5;

do until (last.ID);

set test4;
by flag ID;
if first.ID=0 then do;
if disdiff <= length then date1=lag_disdate;
end;
output;
end;
run;
```

But I'm not sure how to edit it so that the 2/7/2014 is retained for each row.  I did try to use retain but all the date1 still were equal to each lag_disdate, not the 2/7/2014.

Update: if disdiff is > length, date1 would be the dis_date for the record, not the previous date1.

Comment: If disdiff < length, then assign date1 and retain it for the whole by group?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The idea is by the last record for the group, if disdiff < length date then date1 is the first dis_date, but date2 is the last dis_date.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what the desired outcome is when `disdiff > length`. Nonetheless, you're almost there, try this :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by ID ;
  retain lag_disdate ;
  if first.ID then lag_disdate = dis_date ;
  else do ;
    if disdiff <= length then date1 = lag_disdate ;
    date2 = dis_date - 1 ;
  end ;

  format date1 date2 mmddyy10. ;
run ;
```

Comment: I tried this on one group (because I have several groups, also categorized by flags) but the date1 changes for each row still.